# MVVM WPF application using WCF but "Model" missing

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, mvvm, model

I'm creating a WPF application with MVVM framework. The data is then retrieved by accessing a WCF service exposing the data based on Entity framework model. Is there anything wrong with this? It seems that the "Model" portion of MVVM seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the design. Ef wcf part will act as model.

[Silverlight-Application-with-MVVM-WCF-and-EF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405415/Silverlight-Application-with-MVVM-WCF-and-EF)

[Silverlight-with-MVVM-and-WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623924/Silverlight-with-MVVM-and-WCF)